# Different margin sizes on odd and even pages

Tags: margins

I am polishing my thesis document. It is based on a custom style derived from `report` and it is supposed to deliver different sizes of margins on odd and even pages, however it doesn't work. In the `.cls` class someone attempted to fix this issue:

```
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0.5in}  % really 1.5in
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0.5in}  % really 1.5in
```

but it doesn't seem to work at all, i.e. when I change the values the document looks the same.The class file is available [here](http://www3.imperial.ac.uk/pls/portallive/docs/1/41657697.ZIP). How can I make it work?

Comment: You may need to pass the `twopage` option to `report`: `\documentclass[twopage]{report}`.  You should still provide a MWE to use with the provided class file, though.

Comment: or in this case, `\documentclass[a4paper,plainchapterheads,yschapters,twoside]{ICMathsThesis}`

Comment: @SeanAllred, it doesn't work sadly. Latex warns that `twopage` option is not recognised.

Comment: @srao, unfortunately this doesn't have any effect. I found a comment in the class file: `if we use the twoside option, we break the spacing rules`, but it doesn't say how to get it to work...

Comment: As an aside, if they knew how to get it to work, they would have implemented it.  It would really help if you posted a minimal document using this class so we can help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `twoside` option seems to work fine for me, unless I am missing something. Here's a **MWE**:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,plainchapterheads,yschapters,twoside, truedoublelespace]{ICMathsThesis}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{High Accuracy Methods for the Solution to Two Point Boundary Value
Problems}
\author{Steven David Capper}
\department{Mathematics}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Note that I am using the following settings in the .cls file for illustration purpose.

```
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0.9in}  % odd page left margin = 1 inch + \oddsidemargin ==> http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Page_Layout#Page_dimensions ; this can be negative
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0.5in}  % even page left margin = 1 inch + \evensidemargin ; this can be negative
\setlength{\textwidth}{5.0in}
```

With `truedoublespace` option:
[image: doublespace]

With `singlespace` option:
[image: singlespace]

Comment: Is there any scientific way to make it symmetric, i.e. the left margin on the odd pages should be the same as the right margin on even pages?

Comment: It should be easy to calculate :) My understanding is that `pagewidth` = `textwidth` + [(`\oddsidemargin` or `\evensidemargin`) + 1 inch] + right margin`

Comment: So how can I check what are `pagewidth`, `textwidth` or `right margin` in this particular case?

Comment: Pagewidth is the width of the page (a4paper in this case), textwidth is set in the .cls file as shown above. Right margin can then be easily calculated from these values.